# Client Protocols and Alias missing on sql native

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-native-client, sql-server-2022

No Client Protocols or Alias has anything under. Please see attached pic.

[image: missing]

Comment: SNAC11 was removed from SQL Server 2022.

Comment: Also: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/319901/how-to-create-alias-in-sql-server-2022

Comment: SNAC11 also doesn't support versions of SQL Server after 2014.

Comment: @ThomA Eh? I'm able to use SNAC11 in a .NET Fx 4.8 program and SSMS18 to connect to my SQL Server 2022 box just fine.

Comment: Doesn't support doesn't mean doesn't work, @Dai .

Comment: @ThomA Okay now we're debating semantics :)

Comment: But that's the point. If you were to use SSMS 18 to try and design a table on your 2022 instance, for example, *then* you start getting errors. The lack of support *can* mean that only some things don't work, or may not work as expected, @Dai .

Answer (score 0):

Like @Dai said, it was removed from SQL Server 2022.

As described e. g. here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center/dpm/install-dpm?view=sc-dpm-2022 , one can manually install the 2012 runtime and will also see the client protocols on SQL Server 2022. The download can be found at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50402 . Though it did not prompt for restart, it only was visible and working properly after restart (half visible + working before restart). Though Dai already said the same just without the link.